# Adjust Scale / Zoom of All Items - Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm currently using Tailwind / TailwindUI and I would like to scale down ALL items.

Eg I go to my website and Zoom out so everything becomes smaller and the zoom level is 85%

I would like my website to appear at this scale (85%) when a normal user visits.

How would I go about doing this in tailwind?

Comment: Do you want to zoom the content of the website, or do you want to set the zoom scale of the browser?

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution to this is using the browser's built in zoom functionality.

`document.body.style.zoom = "85%"`

I've tested this on Chrome 101.

This is functional Alpine.js component that achieves dynamically changing browser's zoom percentage:

```
 <div x-data="{zoom:100}" class="flex bg-teal-600 text-white mx-3 my-2 rounded-md text-sm font-medium">
    <div @click="document.body.style.zoom = `${zoom-=10}%`" class="bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-400 text-gray-800 font-bold py-1 px-2 pl-3 rounded-l">-</div>
    <div x-text="zoom" class="px-2 pt-1"></div>
    <div @click="document.body.style.zoom = `${zoom+=10}%`" class="bg-gray-300 hover:bg-gray-400 text-gray-800 font-bold py-1 px-2 rounded-r">+</div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use transform & scale property to achieve this.
Just add transform along with the scale-95 etc.
Visit for more reference :-
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/scale
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/transform